Statistical test for variability among more than one group
I am very new to statistics and still learning. Below are the funnel graphs which shows the effect/percentage of polypharmacy(patients with two or more drugs) against practice/hospital population size. The red dot presents size of patients in a practice/hospital. We can see that the level of polypharmacy(2-3 drugs) and excessive polypharmacy(3+ drugs) is either going too high or too low from the mean and going out from the upper and lower confidence interval. This is because we have too much variability in the level of polypharmacy and excessive polypharmacy by practice size population.

Analysis-1: I further fixed the funnel graphs by age groups and  then analyzed the graphs and concluded that the variability was because polypharmacy was more driven by younger age group as compared to old age group. Younger age group was not closed to mean whereas the practices by old age group were within confidence intervals. Now I want to find how I am going to check the variability of polypharmacy by practice size. I used Generalized liner mixed effect model and later used predict function to calculate the SMR or SIR to see the variability between expected and observed polypharmacy patients by practice but the difference is very small. I am looking to find more advanced graphical statistical methods  to analyse this variability.
Analysis-2:I calculated the proportion of polypharmacy for all practices, arranged them in descending order by proportion. I selected the top 8 and bottom 8 practices from the descending order and plotted the proportion of polypharmacy and the total population by age group. I can see that in the bottom 8 practices, I have high number of younger age people but the proportion of polypharmacy is low, say 1000 patients in 18-25 and polypharmacy proportion is 0.1. Whereas in the top 8 practices, I have low numbers by age group but the proportion is high, say 135 in 18-25 and polypharmacy proportion is 0.5.
Looking For:
Based on these hypothesis, Is there any  statistical test by which I can prove that why varibility is too high or low in the practices ? or to find out the outlier practices by varibility ?
